# Overriden toString() not called when object inialized with object literal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following problem: I have a class Foo which overrides the default implementation of toString().

```
class Foo {
   bar: string;

   toString(): string {
      return this.bar;
   }
}
```

When I initialize a fresh variable with an (typed) object literal and call toString() on this new object the standard Javascript implementation is called. So that "[object Object]" is printed out into the console.

```
let foo : Foo  = {
   bar: "baz"
}


console.log(foo.toString()) // does not invoke Foo.toString()
```

However, when I create the object with the new operator everything works like a charm:

```
let foo: Foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = "baz"
console.log(foo.toString()); // prints out "baz"
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd like to avoid the second alternative because in reality the Foo object has many (nested) attributes. So that it would lead to very verbose object initializations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example:

```
let foo : Foo  = {
   bar: "baz"
}
```

You're creating an object literal and claiming it has the same interface as `Foo`. It's not an actual instance of `Foo` so it uses the default implementation of `toString()`.

In your second example:

```
let foo: Foo = new Foo();
```

You're creating an actual instance of `Foo` which has your override of `toString()` implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.